# How to prevent two same color for tree nodes?

Tags: html, css, sass, element-ui

I try to change backgraund color for each tree node like this:

```
.el-tree-node {
        &:nth-child(2n + 1) {
            background: #fafafa;
        }
        &:nth-child(2n) {
            background: #f2f2f2;
        }
    }
```

And give result:
[image]

But when I expand children nodes give that two tree node is the same color:
[image]

Can I fix this by using scss?

Comment: we need javascript to do it. because only when a node is expanded , the color should change. or your primary nodes will not be having the alternate color scheme

Comment: For render tree I use this component https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/tree and dont think thet it can do by using javascript or events of thet component.